# Docker: share data between containers in non-persistent way to allow for code upgrade

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-volume

In a php-fpm and nginx container setup the source code usually needs to be available to both containers. In my case I'd like to dockerize Magento. In Magento the nginx is configured in such a way that it looks for the existence of files before it commits the request to the php engine.

According to the best practices from Docker for an production environment I copied the source code into the php container during the build process. My first idea to share the source code with the nginx container was to use a named volume that is mounted to the root of both containers. However, the data in named volumes persist even after editing the source code and rebuilding the php container. This comes in handy for dynamic content like file uploads etc. but how do I upgrade the source code? Should I delete the volume everytime the source code is changed? How do I persist dynamic content in this case?

In a nutshell:

- I'd like to have non-persistent volume to share source code between php and nginx
- A persistent volume (but still shared with nginx) for folders with dynamic content (e.g. file uploads)

For Magento that would be:

- Non-persistent volume for files and folders like `./index.php`, `./vendor/`, `./app/` (except `./app/etc/env.php` and `./app/etc/config.php` since that are configuration files), etc.
- Persistent volume for files and folders like `./pub/media/`, `./app/etc/env.php`, `./app/etc/config.php`, etc.

Comment: any updates? :) Did you solve this?

Comment: Somewhat: for production I copy the source code into each container and only share uploaded files etc., but the problem still persists in the development stage. For now I remove the named volume in the case that the source code of the framework changes. Here is what I came up with: https://github.com/zsoerenm/magento2-docker#get-your-source-code-into-the-container